# Need to help cleaning data imported from a CSV file

Tags: csv

I have a data set in a CSV file where all of the data is encased within quotations ("). For example:

```
"10/10/2008,""15:48:09"",""760.40"","" -N-       NONE"""
"10/10/2008,""16:00:00"",""754.66"","" -N-       NONE"""
"10/10/2008,""16:15:00"",""761.83"","" -N-       NONE"""
"10/10/2008,""16:30:00"",""758.24"","" -N-       NONE"""
```

I have imported the csv file but the results still include quotations in the dataframe.  For example:

```
0 "10/10/2008   "16:00:00""  "754.66""  " -N-   NONE""""
```

I need either a new method of importing this data from the CSV or a method for removing the extra quotation marks from the data.

This is how I imported the data:

```
NAME = pd.read_table('FileName.csv', sep=',"')
```

I have tried to delete the quotations using a number of ideas I found on this site, but I get errors that I cant decipher.  FYI, I am VERY new to this, if you couldn't tell.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is badly formed CSV and you must fix it before trying to use it. First you need to remove the leading and trailing double quotes, and then replace the 2 x double quotes with single ones.

Like this...

```
10/10/2008,"15:48:09","760.40"," -N-       NONE"
10/10/2008,"16:00:00","754.66"," -N-       NONE"
10/10/2008,"16:15:00","761.83"," -N-       NONE"
10/10/2008,"16:30:00","758.24"," -N-       NONE"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try again removing the quotations marks. then to import it use ',' as the only delimiter:
NAME = pd.read_table('FileName.csv', sep=',')